# Android Studio not able to exclude sub dependecy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

Now I have a gradle file, I exclude the support group already:

```
// URBAN AIR notification
compile ('com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'

        }
```

But still when I check the dependency structure, `support-v4` is still there:

```
+--- com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+ -> 8.3.2
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
```

I also tried

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

and

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

But nothing is working.
Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: try file->invalidate cache / restart

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
compile ('com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+')
{
  exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```